# sort list of objects based on field which can be null

Tags: java, sorting, null

How to to sort list of objects based on field which can be `null`?

I am trying to do it in following way using `Comparator` interface and collections sort method.
The class is `CustomClass` and the field on which sorting is to be done is `createDate`

```
Comparator comparator=new Comparator<CustomClass>(){
        public int compare(CustomClass o1, CustomClass o2) {
            if(o1.getCreateDate()==null && o2.getCreateDate()==null){
                return 0;
            }
            else if(o1.getCreateDate()==null && o2.getCreateDate()!=null){
                return 1;
            }
            else if(o1.getCreateDate()!=null && o2.getCreateDate()==null){
                return -1;
            }
            else{
                if(o1.getCreateDate().equals(o2.getCreateDate())){
                    return 0;   
                }
                else if(o1.getCreateDate().after(o2.getCreateDate())){
                    return 1;   
                }
                else{
                    return -1;
                }
            }                       
        }
    };
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're willing to use [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), then you can use [`ComparisonChain`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html) and [`Ordering`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/OrderingExplained) to make things more succinct.

```
public int compare(CustomClass o1, CustomClass o2)
{
  return ComparisonChain.start()
    .compare(o1.getCreateDate(), o2.getCreateDate(), Ordering.natural().nullsLast())
    .result();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Assuming `getCreateDate()` returns an instance of [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), you can clean up the code a bit. The [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo-java.util.Date-)'s method's contract specifies that it throws a `NullPointerException` if a date is compared to `null` (like any `Comparable` class should do), so you'll have to handle those directly. However, if both are non-`null`, you shouldn't reimplement the comparing logic, but rely on `Date`'s implementation:

```
Comparator<CustomClass> comparator = new Comparator<CustomClass>(){
    public int compare(CustomClass o1, CustomClass o2) {
        if (o1.getCreateDate() == null && o2.getCreateDate() == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (o1.getCreateDate() == null && o2.getCreateDate() != null) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (o1.getCreateDate() != null && o2.getCreateDate() == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        else{
            // Just use java.util.Date's logic:
            return o1.getCreateDate().compareTo(o2.getCreateDate());
        }                       
    }
};
```

**EDIT:**

This is quite an old question, but just to complete the picture, in Java 8, the `Comparator` class itself can do the heavy lifting for you:

```
Comparator<CustomClass> comparator = 
    Comparator.comparing(CustomClass::getCreateDate, 
                         Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You do need all of that to ensure that the `null` values always sort to the end of the list and otherwise you sort by date. You could simplify your code a bit by delegating to the built-in `compareTo` or by using a declarative Guava `Ordering`.